# TensorFlow: Get input batch from numpy array for 3D CNN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have 3D image(tiff) data and each volume inside a folder. I want to read the data and make batch tensor for convolution network. I can read the data as numpy array but I don't how to make batch tensor input for CNN. Here is the code I have

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
data_dir = 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/Segmentation/DeepLearning/L-net/data/'
data_folders = os.listdir(data_dir)
train_input = []
train_output = []
test_input = []
test_output = []

for idx, folder in enumerate(data_folders):
        im = io.imread(data_dir+folder+'/f0.tiff')
        im = im/im.max()
        train_input.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(im, dtype=tf.float32))
        im = io.imread(data_dir+folder+'/g0.tiff')
        im = im/im.max()
        train_output.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(im, dtype=tf.float32))
```

Since I am using 3D filters for CNN, input should 5D tesnor. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: You may need just 4D as input. It will become 5D after first convolution layer.
for 3 to 4 D conversion you stack images or use tf.expand_dims is using single image per batch.

Comment: If you read 3D volumes with `imageio` consider using `volread` instead of `imread`

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you have to load all data at once into memory and also you have to take care of all dimensions. I would suggest using Keras `flow_from_directory` and `generators`. Keras has this `ImageDataGenerator` class which allows the users to perform image collection from directories, change all images to any size you want, shuffle them, ... . You can find the documentation [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) at their website.

> Download the train dataset and test dataset, extract them into 2 different folders named as “train” and “test”. The train folder should contain ‘n’ folders each containing images of respective classes. For example, In the Dog vs Cats data set, the train folder should have 2 folders, namely “Dog” and “Cats” containing respective images inside them.

This is an example on how to create a dataset for your model's input:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=r"C:/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/Segmentation/DeepLearning/L-net/data/",
    target_size=(224, 224), # the size of your input images
    color_mode="rgb", # could be grayscale or rgb
    batch_size=32, # Number of images in each batsh
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True, # Whether to shuffle the images or not
    seed=42 # Random seed for applying random image augmentation
)
```

You can perform training like this:

```
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=10
)
```